# Get average-dominant color from a rectangle on screen (live/python)

Tags: python, opencv, screenshot

What I am trying to do is set a rectangle on the PC screen (Windows 10). Every 5-10 seconds, get the average color of that rectangle.

Example: rectangle 50x50 on bottom left of the screen > get average color. If redish, do this. If blueish, do that. Repeat.

My idea is that I can get a screenshot (Pyautogui probably), save the image, then crop the desired rectangle (OpenCV), save the image again and analyze it (OpenCV/Numpy).

However, I think this would be very CPU intensive. Where could I start, if I wanted something lightweight and fast? What libraries would you suggest?

Comment: What is the background color or image? Is it totally black except for the rectangle? Once you have the screenshot in Python Opencv, you do not need to save the data to disk. You can analyze it without saving to disk. Crop your rectangle and reduce the number of colors, then get the histogram and find the most frequent color.

Comment: A simplistic approach is to get the rectangle pixels and then use np.mean() or cv2.mean() to get the average color. If the background is black, you can use np.nonzero() to find the pixels in the rectangle, then get the average from cv2.mean or np.mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this task more efficiently but even if you do the way you describe, these are not computationally intensive operations. All should take less than 0.1 seconds. As @fmw42 described, you don't need to save, do the analysis on the fly.

The libraries you mention are good.

1. Get [screenshot](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/01/01/taking-screenshots-with-opencv-and-python/). Store it in memory (not disk)
2. [mean](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html): get the mean of each channel color, and get the dominant color.
3. [save image on disk](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-save-image-example/)